# Large file to LookUp other large file when files are dependent- Mule ESB

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Could you please suggest. I have two files each have 80 to 90k product  and these two files are interlinked with each other(one file have information on other) and i need to generate one single file  by looking up the other files. These files  probably comes in the sameTime with different name.
Both the files are csv and i need to generate the new csv.

Is that the only way I should keep any one of these files in memory  and keep looking by iterating.

I planned to use Batch inside dataMapper. Is there any way we can keep the first file in Datamapper userDefined table or something like that.And the getting the new file to make a look up on it.( I'm not provided with external DB)

If any one of the file have some 5000 or 10k lines it the sense, i can keep that in memory and make the 80k file to look on it. I'm not comfortable to keep 80 or 90k file in memory.

Have reference this link: [Mule ESB - design a multi file processing flow when files are dependent on each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393755/mule-esb-design-a-multi-file-processing-flow-when-files-are-dependent-on-each).

Could you please suggest me the best solution. 
Also any idea How long to process the file it does take,  Thanks in advance.

Mule studio:5.3.1 and Runtime: 3.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of the problem as two distinct events from Mule's perspective, and plan to keep state from the first one in a "database" of some kind.  This doesn't have to be an Oracle cluster or anything, you can run [H2](http://h2database.com/html/quickstart.html) in process or [Redis](http://redis.io/) on the same server as Mule for example.

I think you're on the right track with the [Batch](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/batch-processing) idea.  When the first file is received, I'd create a record for each in a batch job.  Then when the second file is received, I'd run a second batch job that looks up the relevant information from the database, and generates the CSV file you need.  It could also remove the records that have been matched from the database in a subsequent batch step.

For the transformations, I'd recommend trying [DataWeave](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/dataweave) instead of DataMapper.  It's a better way to write transformation logic, and Mulesoft has deprecated DataMapper, to be removed as of Mule 4.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree to go Dataweaver. H2 or Redis is a open source? which one is best to use with Mule.  Is it flexible to use in Mule as part of temporary DB to do a Lookup. Suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I have used both, and both are open source.  Redis is simple, as there's no need to define tables first, but it does require you to run another process outside of Mule.  Redis is not a SQL database, just a key value store, and has its own mule connector.  H2 is nice because it runs completely in process, it just takes some work to run your DDL only once, before you try to insert or select any rows.  H2 is a normal SQL database that you'd use the database connector to access.